# How did Giles get to know who is the Key in Buffy the Vampire Slayer?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer

In Buffy the Vampire Slayer in the season where Dawn, Buffy's sister, was new and the hidden key, Buffy finds out through a ritual that Dawn is something different and not her real sister. Her mother finds out because she has her mental episodes and Buffy fills in the gaps.

**But how does Giles know?** In the middle of the season (5), they have a secret discussion between Buffy, Giles and mother, while Dawn overhears their discussion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Buffy tells Giles in Season 5 Episode 6 "Family":

> Cut to Joyce's house, night. Giles and Buffy sit in the living room.
> They talk quietly.
>
> GILES: Uh, I don't know what to say.
>
> BUFFY: Tell me about it. (looks toward the stairs)
>
> GILES: She has no idea?
>
> BUFFY: No. She thinks she's my kid sister.
>
> GILES: Are you going to tell her?
>
> BUFFY: How can I? (sighs, gets up)
> She'd freak, and that's the last thing we need.

[(Source)](https://tvshowtranscripts.ourboard.org/viewtopic.php?f=122&t=8388)